# Communicate with embedded HTTP Server via XTC_APP_ENDPOINT

Tags: unity-game-engine, xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I'm referring to the implementation outlined in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnAenNaEpJk

This works fine running locally using the IP address of my device over any port (as long as the client and server use the same port).

Test client:

```
var url = isTestCloud ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("XTC_APP_ENDPOINT") : "http://" + deviceIp + ":8081";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient {
    BaseAddress = new Uri(url),
};
```

In App:

```
HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
var prefixes = new [] {
    "http://*:8081/",
};
foreach (string s in prefixes)
    _listener.Prefixes.Add (s);
_listener.Start ();
```

This works great running locally, but when trying to run in Test Cloud, I get a `System.TimeoutException` in my Test while trying to connect to the game server.

From the video, James makes it clear that you must be listening on port `8081`, however this was a couple of years ago and I'm wondering if it has changed. I also tried changing `8081` to `37777`. But I still had the same result.

I noticed the XTC_APP_ENDPOINT env variable returns something like: `http://devicehost7.prod:37777/wd/token-1acaf8c0-2987-4a49-aa5b-3ab795ecb910/`

I adjusted my server to use `37777`, same result.
I tried again adjusting my prefix: `var prefixes = new [] { "http://*:37777/*/token-*/", };`, but always get the same result (`System.TimeoutException`).

Is there any documentation I can read up on regarding how to interact with an embedded HTTP server? Or can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Loren

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with support, it seems TestCloud was producing an incorrect value for XTC_APP_ENDPOINT.

They've addressed it, and now my original code now works perfectly over port 8081!